# DC plug identification

Tags: plug

It's a 9.5V 0.6A adapter with a really strange plug like a smaller half-flat IEC C7/C8 but much smaller, like 12mm wide. What is this called or is it totally proprietary?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are there any other markings on the power supply enclosure?

Comment: The manufacturer but I didn't want to include that because spam/advertisment/etc. I mean.. either there's a standard plug for such a strange voltage or there isn't.

Comment: hm, that's not really helpful; not like a spammer will spam the manufacturer after it OCR'ed the name from a photo :) and regarding spamming this site: as manufacturer might be relevant information for your problem, it's certainly no issue including it. Let's see: this thing is probably meant for the european market, seeing CE and european Battery recycling symbols, right? But you're measuring in inches. I have a terrible suspicion: you're in Canada!

Comment: (not that it changes anything; I don't think this is a standard plug, especially because they felt the need to put a polatrity drawing on the supply)

Comment: _"either there's a standard plug for such a strange voltage or there isn't."_ - define 'standard'.

Comment: The  Messograf has both inches and mm (look closer) but yes, I am in Canada but this adapter is European and that's why I am looking: a Schuko to NEMA plug shape adapter works but a native would be neater. "I don't think this is a standard plug," that's what I am afraid of too.